# Open links placed in different divs in one div with php

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I've been looking at this for a few hours now and I've probably overlooked something silly, but I really can't get this to work.
I have created a .php file with four different php-files which are included with the

I am practicing with building websites and my first website used to solve this problem with frames, I could simply target every anchor tag to the mainframe and it worked perfectly. However, as frames are a deprecated feature, I decided to replace them. I can't seem to get the links working however.

There are tons of answers around, and that's probably the biggest problem, I can't figure out which solution fits to my specific design. Sorry if this is a doublepost.

This is what I've created so far:

```
 <div id="header" class="header">
    <img src="Images/metallic.png" width="125" height="125" alt=""/>
    <img src="Images/database.png" width="85%" height="125" align="right" alt=""/>
</div>
<?php include 'Parts/upperdivs.php'; ?>
<?php include 'Parts/navigation.php'; ?>
<?php include 'Pages/main.php'; ?>
```

As said, there are buttons with hyperlinks in the navigation page and 'normal' hyperlinks in the upperdivs. Is there a way to open all those hyperlinks in the main content div, without having to copy all I've already got? I've read a lot of information about Ajax and the PHP-load feature, but I'm not sure what I should use. I've tried adding it as well, but couldn't get it to work. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I've also tried using an Iframe with an Iframe ID, and pointing to it using the target-tag. The problem is that the pages differ very much in content - if I set the height of the Iframe to, let's say, 1000px, it's way to large and you can scroll too far down on pages with minimal content, and if I set it to 100px, I get two scrollbars, one on the Iframe and one on the right side of the webpage, which is very ugly - and above all - very annoying.

Comment: I'm not sure of your question. Does the site work, and you're just asking for a shortcut? If the answer is yes, then read my answer below.

Comment: Sorry if my question is unclear. The site is working as in: it's displaying everything on the place I want. But the hyperlinks aren't working - and I don't know what I should do to get them working.[I've screenshotted and edited the current layout](http://oi42.tinypic.com/3090lys.jpg) and used Paint to describe what I would like it to do. I hope you understand what I mean, sorry for any confusion :)

Comment: That would be as simple as creating seasons.php and signup.php and following the pattern in my answer, if that makes sense. :)

Comment: Ah, now I get it, that definitely makes sense. I tried this and it works perfectly, I only had to make the links root-relative. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If you don't mind, please vote my answer up as well by clicking the arrow.

Comment: Well, I don't mind, but this website does, as I haven't earned enough reputation yet to upvote answers. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being clear on exactly what you're asking, I assume you're looking for an easier way to handle includes.

This is not the best way to do it, but I would have each page be in the URL you want, and have the 'Parts' pages be in a separate folder.

```
/
|  main.php
|  about.php
|  news.php
/  Parts
   |  navigation.php
   |  upperdivs.php
   |  EVERY_PAGE.php
```

Then as a shortcut, you could make EVERY_PAGE.php like this:

```
<div id="header" class="header">
    <img src="Images/metallic.png" width="125" height="125" alt=""/>
    <img src="Images/database.png" width="85%" height="125" align="right" alt=""/>
</div>
<?php include 'Parts/upperdivs.php'; ?>
<?php include 'Parts/navigation.php'; ?>
```

On each page you would do this:

```
<?php include 'Parts/EVERY_PAGE.php'; ?>

///
// ... Page code here ...
//
```

Also, it's good to learn some better styles of coding, but this will get the job done in a clean and quick way.